# How to prompt for exit when back button is pressed?

Tags: xamarin.forms, async-await, xamarin.android, back-button

Recently I had to add a feature to a **Xamarin Forms** mobile application. The feature shows a yes/no prompt when the user presses the back button (in Android phones). If the user selects *No* it will discard the button, otherwise, it will apply the back button which will hide the application.

I knew that for **detecting** the back button in **Xamarin Forms** I have to override the **Page.OnBackButtonPressed** method. And for bypassing the back button it should return **true**, like this:

```cs
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    if (DisplayAlert("", "Are you sure?", "Yes", "No"))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

But the problem lies in the fact that **Page.DisplayAlert** is an async method and must be called on the main (UI) thread. So after a lot of searches, I came up with this idea which I want to share.

I'm open to any ideas/suggestions on how to improve.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is **emulating** the back button after getting the result of **DisplayAlert**.

For emulating the back button I found calling **Activity.OnBackPressed** useful.

For sure it is not the best idea but it is easy to call this method in Shared/PCL Xamarin Forms project in this manner:

1. Defining a public static **Action** field somewhere (e.g. the page)
2. Initializing this field in the **MainActivity** class by **OnBackPressed**

So the whole solution would be like this:

**Xamarin Forms Page Class**

```cs
class MyPage : ContentPage
{
    public static Action EmulateBackPressed;

    private bool AcceptBack;

    protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
    {
        if (AcceptBack)
            return false;

        PromptForExit();
        return true;
    }

    private async void PromptForExit()
    {
        if (await DisplayAlert("", "Are you sure to exit?", "Yes", "No"))
        {
            AcceptBack = true;
            EmulateBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

**Xamarin Android MainActivity Class**

```cs
public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        MyPage.EmulateBackPressed = OnBackPressed;

        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

Comment: EmulateBackPressed in App.EmulateBackPressed = OnBackPressed throws error - App does not contain a definition for 'EmulateBackPressed'

Comment: I've edited the answer. Just replace 'App.EmulateBackPressed' with 'MyPage.EmulateBackPressed'. Thanks.

Comment: Now it works :). Do you think it can also work on iOS and Windows mobile devices? I don't have access to iOS emulator nor Windows phone, so don't know..

Comment: iPhones don't have a back button. I'm not sure about Windows Phones (I guess they have). I have not tested this on a Windows Phone but I think it should work.

Comment: Oh gosh, I forgot about iPhone's single button. Thanks, your solution is very useful

Comment: I'm glad it helped :)

Comment: Can't find EmulateBackPressed, am i missing a reference?

Comment: You need to declare this `public static Action EmulateBackPressed;` in your **ContentPage** (Here in this example is **MyPage**) and reference it in the **MainActivity.OnCreate** method accordingly.

Comment: how should do this be working if page is not even initialized you set a reference. Doing a static reference will cause memory leak.

Comment: @batmaci It's a static property. No need to page initialization. As I mentioned in my answer it can be placed in any class and it is just a single `Action` field that doesn't cause any memory leakage. The solution I presented here is the simplest one. Maybe creating a `DependencyService` is more modular.